# How to get Guard "live" output in terminal

Tags: ruby, readline, pytest, guard

I'm currently using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) along with the [guard-pytest](https://github.com/kazufusa/guard-pytest) plugin to run the appropriate tests when files change. I was using [sniffer](https://github.com/jeffh/sniffer), but it doesn't seem to have as much control as I would like, I want to run specific tests, not all of them (and I am a long-time guard user). I am on Mac OSX.

The problem is, Guard or Ruby or Python seem to be buffering the output, so that if a test takes a while to run, I have to wait a while with no feedback in the terminal on the tests in progress. Once the tests have completed, all the output comes at once. Anyone have any experience with getting "live" output from Guard? I messed around with `$stdout = sync`, `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` and various attempts at getting readline support, but here I am, asking on StackOverflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

guard-pytest doesn't work too well if the commands take time:

https://github.com/kazufusa/guard-pytest/blob/master/lib/guard/pytest.rb#L20

Basically, it collects the output, then outputs it as a whole.

I created a PR to fix this: https://github.com/kazufusa/guard-pytest/pull/2